# Exponent vector from a polynomial over three variables

Tags: functions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to find the exponent vector from a polynomial that has three variables.

For example

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
M = x^4 + x^2 z^4 + y z^6 + z^10 + y^4
p = CoefficientRules[M][[All, 1]]
```

works well but when the exponent is rational it does not work.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
M1 = x^4 + x^(1/2) z^4 + y z^6 + z^10 + y^4
p1 = CoefficientRules[M1][[All, 1]]
```

I want the exponent vectors even if some exponents are rational.

Comment: may be because `CoefficientRules` works only on polynomials. So you can't  have powers that are fractions. It is no longer a polynomial then. You can check using `PolynomialQ[M1, x]` before calling `CoefficientRules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
M = x^4 + x^(1/2) z^4 + y z^6 + z^10 + y^4;
Table[Exponent[M[[i]], {x, y, z}], {i, 1, Length[M]}]

{{4, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 0}, {1/2, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 10}}
```

Comment: For brevity, you could also use `Exponent[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ List @@ M`.

Comment: It doesn't work for `M = y z^6`.

Comment: Yes, the Length[] function is inconsistent, so for single terms Exponent[M,{x,y,z}] seems to work.